# `.at()` function no longer available for web3.eth.Contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm following a guide that uses some web3 code written 3 years ago.

I am trying to use the TimeLockedWallet.info() call to get information about a wallet.

Below are my two smart contracts.

*TimeLockedWalletFactory.sol*

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./TimeLockedWallet.sol";

contract TimeLockedWalletFactory {

    mapping(address => address[]) wallets;

    function getWallets(address _user)
        public
        view
        returns(address[])
    {
        return wallets[_user];
    }

    function newTimeLockedWallet(uint256 _unlockDate)
        payable
        public
        returns(address wallet)
    {
        // Create new wallet.
        wallet = new TimeLockedWallet(msg.sender, _unlockDate);

        // Add wallet to sender's wallets.
        wallets[msg.sender].push(wallet);

        // Send ether from this transaction to the created contract.
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);

        // Emit event.
        Created(wallet, msg.sender, now, _unlockDate, msg.value);
    }

    // Prevents accidental sending of ether to the factory
    function () public {
        revert();
    }

    event Created(address wallet, address to, uint256 createdAt, uint256 unlockDate, uint256 amount);
}
```

*TimeLockedWallet.sol*

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract TimeLockedWallet {
    address public owner;
    uint256 public unlockDate;
    uint256 public createdAt;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function TimeLockedWallet(address _owner, uint256 _unlockDate) public {
        owner = _owner;
        unlockDate = _unlockDate;
        createdAt = now;
    }

    // keep all the ether sent to this address
    function() public payable {
        Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    // callable by owner only, after specified time
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        require(now >= unlockDate);
        //now send all the balance
        msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
        Withdrew(msg.sender, this.balance);
    }

    function info()
        public
        view
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        return (unlockDate, createdAt, this.balance);
    }

    event Received(address from, uint256 amount);
    event Withdrew(address to, uint256 amount);
    event WithdrewTokens(address tokenContract, address to, uint256 amount);
}
```

And my frontend code tries to get information about the wallet from TimeLockedWallet.sol (unlockDate, owner, createdAt) using the `contract.at()` function. However, I get an error

```
VM3368:1 Uncaught TypeError: c_timeLockedWallet.at is not a function
```

*App.js*

```
import TimeLockedWallet from "./contracts/TimeLockedWallet.json";
import TimeLockedWalletFactory from "./contracts/TimeLockedWalletFactory.json";

const c_timeLockedWalletFactory = new web3.eth.Contract(
  TimeLockedWalletFactory.abi,
  deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
);
const c_timeLockedWallet = new web3.eth.Contract(
  TimeLockedWallet.abi,
);

const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

await c_timeLockedWalletFactory.methods.newTimeLockedWallet(unixTime).send({ from: accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") });
const wallets = await c_timeLockedWalletFactory.methods.getWallets(accounts[0]).call();


c_timeLockedWallet.at(wallets[0]).then(function(walletInstance){return walletInstance.info();}).then(function(info){console.log(info)})
```

Is there another method to use to make this call? I've tried reading the web3 docs, but have come up short.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

The API changed from

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(contractAddress);
```

to

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)
```

So instead of my code

```
const c_timeLockedWallet = new web3.eth.Contract(
  TimeLockedWallet.abi,
);
c_timeLockedWallet.at(wallets[0]).then(function(walletInstance){return walletInstance.info();}).then(function(info){console.log(info)})
```

it should be

```
const c_timeLockedWallet = new web3.eth.Contract(
  TimeLockedWallet.abi, wallets[0]
);
c_timeLockedWallet.methods.info().call().then(console.log)
```